# Iterating through files being read in by C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2015

I am building a Winforms application with C# and there are 3 files I will be reading in and then iterating over them to perform some function to verify them. I'm unable to iterate and can't seem to figure it out as I am learning Winforms and C#.

```
// store each file path into a string
string nailAssignmentResult = textBox1.Text;
string nailFixtureResult = textBox2.Text;
string nailContactResult = textBox3.Text;
```

The declaration above stores the file path from 3 textboxes into string variables for me to iterate through.

I have tried a foreach loop and for loop but I can't seem to figure out how to iterate through them. I would like to parse the information in each file into list separate by a space.

```
namespace FixtureReports
{
    public partial class btnFileSelect : Form
    {
        // contructor
        public btnFileSelect()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // this will do the verification 
        private void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // clear textbox each time its clicked
            results.Clear();

            //store each file path into a string
            string nailAssignmentResult = textBox1.Text;
            string nailFixtureResult = textBox2.Text;
            string nailContactResult = textBox3.Text;

            // error for if all three paths are empty 
            TextBox errorMessage = results;
            if (nailAssignmentResult == "" && nailFixtureResult == "" && nailContactResult == "")
                errorMessage.Text = "ERROR: Cannot have empty path for all three reports!!";

            // verifying each file path exists
            if (File.Exists(nailAssignmentResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("Nail Assignment Report Found");

            if (File.Exists(nailFixtureResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("\r\nNail Fixture Report Found");

            if (File.Exists(nailContactResult))
                errorMessage.AppendText("\r\nNail Contact List Report Found");


            // grab each file and iterate through each of them 

            // parse the contents into a list separated by a space horizontally

            // for each line of data, what needs to be compared

            // take in receiver pin and plug into brians function to get pylon

            // compare to existing pylon designation in report and see if it matches

            // have a counter for how many were correct 

            // if incorrect, display pylon blocks and receiver pins
        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailFixtureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailAssignmentBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        // prompt for file selection
        private void nailContactBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox3.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the codes you have written?

Comment: I have added my code for the entire application so far in my question @MasudSafari

Comment: What do you mean by "iterating over them"? Did a coworker or your course instructor write those comments and are you stuck at step 1? Do you mean that for each of those three files, you want to read all their contents? Please clarify.

Comment: Coworker wrote those and its just psuedo code for the rest of the application. Yes, I would like to read all the contents for each of those files. @CodeCaster

Comment: You might want to read up on the topic of *serialization*, i.e. how to convert objects into binary data, and back again. See for example [json serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to "iterate" you need a collection. You can create a simple array from the three variables:

```
var files = new[] {nailAssignmentResult, nailFixtureResult, nailContactResult};
```

and iterate over *that*, but if you have the "processing" in a function where you can just pass in the filename (and whatever other information is neeed, then you don't *need* to iterate:

```
var assignmentResults = ProcessFile(nailAssignmentResult);
var fixtureResults = ProcessFile(nailFixtureResult);
var contractResults = ProcessFile(nailContactResult);
```

These are only two options - there are many ways that this could be done, including creating an iterator function that uses `yield return` to return each value, but I see no need for anything fancier that a simple array of the values.

Comment: Okay great! I will attempt to implement and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
foreach( var line in File.ReadLines(nailAssignmentResult))
{
    // ...
}
```

You need to work out more of your own code, and be clear on the spec, before going deeper.

Also: *do not check `File.Exists()`*! Existence is only one reason among several you might not be able to open a file. Additionally, the file system is **volatile**, meaning a file's status can change in the short time between when you check it and when you attempt to open it. For this reason, you have to be able to handle an exception when attempting to open a file, regardless of any prior checks.

Therefore the `Exists()` check really just boils down to an extra unnecessary (wasteful) I/O operation, and disk I/O is among the slowest things you can do in a single computer. In nearly all cases it's better to put your effort solely into the exception handler.